# HTTP GET request not working as expected

Tags: api, http, get

I am trying to determine which university a user is from based off of the domain of their email. I am using the following api: https://github.com/Hipo/university-domains-list-api which I works for some parameters.

```
/search?name=Middle
```

works like I I expect it to. When I run

```
   http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?domain=upenn.edu
```

I want to get this back

```
[{
 "web_pages": [
  "http://www.upenn.edu/"
],
"name": "University of Pennsylvania",
"alpha_two_code": "US",
"state-province": null,
"domains": [
  "upenn.edu"
],
"country": "United States"
}]
```

However, I seem to get the whole json file back. I am completely new to working with APIs so I could be making a very basic mistake or maybe I'm missing something entirely. Also I apologize if some of terminology is off. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: What response did you get?  Its seems reasonable to get a full object/class response in JSON format...Is the size of the object the problem? Or the complexity?...Perhaps another parameter controls the response 'size'

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong. It appears this API only allows searching by the name, and filtering by the country. It doesn't allow filtering by the domain.
They have only published 3 ways to get the data:

1. All: http://universities.hipolabs.com
2. Search by partial name http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=middle
3. Filter by country (full name) http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?name=middle&country=turkey

So I recommend you parse the whole response (from 1 above) and cache it on your server, then refresh every hour (or day), and then query your own cache.